# Suitescript - Hiding line fields during Sales Order/Invoice entry

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to HIDE certain fields (such as costs) from certain Netsuite roles if they are not permitted to see costs.

I can prevent users changing sell prices without the proper authority with **nlapiDisableLineItemField** during PostSourcing and validateline etc...

But with cost fields, I'd like to HIDE them if the user does not have COST access. I realize I can do this by creating a separate form that does not include costs, but if I can hide information via the script, it means less duplication of effort down the track with other things I have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `beforeLoad userevent script` to hide body level fields (but, it is not possible to do the same for line item field, as there isn't any API on nlobjform to allow that. For sublist/lineitem fields You will have to write a client script validations or remove the field from the form like you have been already doing as you mentioned in your question).

In you beforeload user event script you get access to form and then use something like below to hide body level fields.

```
function beforeLoadEntryFunction(type, form)
{
  if(nlapiGetRole() === 'NON_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_ID'){
   form.getField(YOUR_BODY_FIELD_ID).setDisplayType('hidden');
  }
}
```

Edit:
For sublist/lineitem fields create a `client script` with code as

```
function clientScriptEntryFunction(type, form)
    {
      if(nlapiGetRole() === 'NON_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_ID'){
       form.getField(YOUR_BODY_FIELD_ID).setDisplayType('hidden');
       nlapiDisableLineItemField(SUBLIST_ID, LINE_FIELD_ID);
      }
    }
```

And in  `before load user event` use `form.setScript(YOUR_CLIENT_SCRIPT_ID)` as you already have access to the form object.

Remember, client script should be a global client script

Comment: OK, looks like the form method is the only option for now. Maybe Netsuite will add that functionality some time in the future.

Comment: to add, you may want to call the client script entry function after document.ready event to be sure NS scripts are available/downloaded or else do a simple setTimeout until 'window.nlapiDisableLineItemField !== undefined'

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is purely aesthetic, you can do a Client side onLoad script and hide the fields via jQuery, you can do a select by name which wouldn't change even on version upgrades.

The jQuery library is included on NetSuite.

Comment: writing a DOM dependency is NOT recommended in NetSuite as things will break up any time, NetSuite changes it and your app won'q qualify for SuiteApp, if you are planning for one

Comment: Its is not. It is a hack. But figuring from the other available responses, it might be his only choice now.

Comment: also, i think you can't guarantee that name attribute in html tags would be constant. it could be less likely to change, but there is no official words on it and netsuite can consider this as DOM dependency